# Is it a good idea to load all user data on top of each file including sensitive information?

Tags: object-oriented, php, security, class-design

I've written a User class like this:

```
<?php

class User{

    private $id;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $name;
    private $email;
    private $key;
    private $phone;
    private $is_verified;
    private $last_login;
    private $last_ip;
    private $language;
    private $is_loggedIn;

    function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function __set ($property , $value){
        $this->$property = $value;
    }

    public function __get($property){
        return $this->$property;
    }

    public function check_login(){

    }
}

?>
```

Now, I'm thinking to set all the private parameters in `check_login()` function with user data. This function will be called on top of each and every file. Will it be a good idea to load all user data including password, email, phone etc on top of each file?

Comment: When you say *password*, do you mean *password-hash*? Because login/registration/password change are the only places where you have the plaintext password (because the user sent it as part of the current request) and those are not a field in a User class.

Comment: @CodesInChaos yes properly hashed passwords.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "good idea?"  Do you mean secure?  Performant?  Having the lowest number of calories?

Comment: @RobertHarvey security is my main concern.

Comment: maybe a better question is why are you doing this in the first place? obvs security is always going to be a bit better if you load less info

Comment: "yes properly hashed passwords." [I don't think you understand what the word properly means](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/8ai480/is_it_a_good_idea_to_load_all_user_data_on_top_of/dwz692s/) :P

Comment: @PeeHaa I am using Pligg, PHP based CMS for my project. They use this hash function. There is nothing I can do about it. This is not the best soulution but this is still not the worst.

Comment: @KshitijKumar it is a terrible non solution for hashing passwords. There are several things you can do about it. For one: don't just said broken solution and leak you users password somewhere in the coming months instead of picking the easy way for yourself. More info: [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/negligence) and [here](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/negligence).

Answer (score 1):

Good idea I wouldn't say, but security wise it shouldn't be a big issue. To make sure you are not leaking sensitive information it is important how you treat it, are passwords properly encrypted/hashed, how do you have it in the session etc. Calling a resource intensive function on top of every file also can hit performance depending on what you execute in your check_login().

It's better to log the user in once and then check the session if the user is logged in or not. Don't perform a full login at the start of each file.